# Word file to json in python

Tags: python, json

I have a few word files (doc and docx) containing data of following form and I need to convert them to JSON:

```
1.Name: ABC, Place: Maryland, Country: US, PHONE NO.:1234567890

2.Name: ABC, Place: Maryland, Country: US, PHONE NO.:1234567890

3.Name: ABC, Place: Maryland, Country: US, PHONE NO.:1234567890
```

What's the easiest way to do this in python?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: yes, but there is nothing mentioned about doc to JSON conversions.

Comment: It seems you could parse the different parts of docx and then use the Json module to build your customized format. Nothing ready to use, sadly

Answer (score 0):

There's a [`docx` module](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/documents.html) (though it explicitly doesn't support old-style `.doc` files), which you could combine with a csv reader to split up the columns, then get your row index out of the first column.

```
from docx import Document
import json

document = Document('existing-document-file.docx')
lines = [para.text for para in document.paragraphs]
lines = [line.partition('.') for line in lines]
lines = [(int(row_num), row_text) for row_num, _, row_text in lines]
lines = [(n, [txt.partition(':') for txt in row_text.split(',')]) for n, row_text in lines]
lines = {n: {key.strip(): val.strip() for key, _, val in row} for n, row in lines}
json_result = json.dumps(lines)
```

With your sample input, I get the following output using this code:

```
'{"1": {"Name": "ABC", "Place": "Maryland", "Country": "US", "PHONE NO.": "1234567890"},
"2": {"Name": "ABC", "Place": "Maryland", "Country": "US", "PHONE NO.": "1234567890"},
"3": {"Name": "ABC", "Place": "Maryland", "Country": "US", "PHONE NO.": "1234567890"}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Libraries to be used:

- For *docx* to *text* conversion use `docx2text`
- for *json* conversion use `json` library
- for storing value in *dictionary* use `defaultdict()` from `collections`

### Steps

1. Convert document to string using `docx2text`
2. Convert string to list of strings , split by new line `\n`character and remove junk empty spaces ''
3. For each element in list split by `:` `,` to do manipulations.
   To remove numerics splice by `:2`
4. Store each key, value pair in dictionary for each item in list `li` in a dictionary
5. Add dict object to `json_li`
6. Call `json.dumps(json_li)` to create json string

#### Code

```
import docx2txt, json, collections
# step 1 get docx text
text = docx2txt.process("F:\workspace\StackOverFlow\guac.docx")
# convert to list
li = [x for x in text.split('\n')]
# remove ''s i.e Nones
li = list(filter(None, li))
print(li)
# json list
json_li = []
# convert and store all values
for x in li:
    x = x[2:] # remove 1. 2. 3. ...
    y = x.split(',')
    print(y)
    d = collections.defaultdict()
    for m in y:
        z = m.split(':')
        z1 = [x.strip() for x in z]
        d[z1[0]] = z1[1]
    json_li.append(d)
# JSON conversion
print(json.dumps(json_li, indent=4))
```

### output

```
['1.Name: ABC, Place: Maryland, Country: US, PHONE NO.:1234567890', '2.Name: ABC, Place: Maryland, Country: US, PHONE NO.:1234567890', '3.Name: ABC, Place: Maryland, Country: US, PHONE NO.:1234567890']
['Name: ABC', ' Place: Maryland', ' Country: US', ' PHONE NO.:1234567890']
['Name: ABC', ' Place: Maryland', ' Country: US', ' PHONE NO.:1234567890']
['Name: ABC', ' Place: Maryland', ' Country: US', ' PHONE NO.:1234567890']
[
    {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Place": "Maryland",
        "Country": "US",
        "PHONE NO.": "1234567890"
    },
    {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Place": "Maryland",
        "Country": "US",
        "PHONE NO.": "1234567890"
    },
    {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Place": "Maryland",
        "Country": "US",
        "PHONE NO.": "1234567890"
    }
]
```

#### Update on doc file

If you have doc files use

```
import textract
text = textract.process("path_to_file")
```

Answer (score -1):

No libraries/built-ins to do that. Easiest way would be to convert the file into a CSV (either yourself by removing all commas then replacing whitespaces with commas or use a program if possible)

Then you can use the DictReader class from the csv package to convert the file into a dictionary, then use the json module to dump it into a json string.

pseudo-code e.g. after converting to csv.

```
import json

from csv import DictReader

COLUMN_NAMES = ['your', 'column', 'names,', '...'] 
    #Or the first row will be the column
    #(and the resulting key in the dictionary ) names

jsonCollection = {}
with open("your_csv_file.csv") as csvFile:
    #fieldnames is optional here
    reader = DictReader(csvFile, fieldnames=COLUMN_NAMES)
    for row in reader:
        for colName, rowVal in row.items():
            jsonCollection.setdefault(colName, []).append(rowVal)

json.dumps(jsonCollection) #should get you what you want
```

Comment: why CSV ? OP says data is in doc and docx

Comment: OP also asks for it in easiest manner; converting a csv to a dictionary (and then to json) is a built-in functionality in python whereas doc/docx isnt as so trivial.

Comment: People downvoting without comment... What's your suggestion?  /shrug