# Loading a .docx file into ETL/ELT tool?

Tags: ms-word, etl, data-analysis, data-warehouse, data-extraction

Could someone please guide me on how to extract a `.docx` file and load it onto a database using an `ETL`(Extract-Transform-Load) or `ELT`(Extract-Load-Transform) tool?

Assuming that the `.docx` file contains mostly unstructured data, isn't it an `ELT` tool I should go for instead of `ETL`?

The `ETL` and `ELT` tools I found this far didn't support the `MS Word` component. What other way is there to extract and store the content in a `.docx` file onto a database?

My requirement is to:

1. Extract the data inside the `.docx` file,
2. Convert them into meaningful data, and
3. Store them onto a `data lake` so I can perform `data analysis`, and take productive decisions based on those results.

It's just like how e-commerce companies convert customer reviews into meaningful data so they can take decisions to boost their sales. In my case, it's `Word` files I need to analyze.

I'm asking this because I've searched for so many `ETL` and `ELT` tools but couldn't find anything that supported `Word` files. Maybe it's because I haven't been searching for the right tool or the right way to do it?

If somebody knows a way, please guide me through the process. What should I start looking for? A tool, or a way to code the entire thing?

I've been looking for an answer for weeks now but didn't find a helpful answer. And it's starting to get really frustrating to see all the tools supporting every other component like social media, MongoDB, or whatever EXCEPT `Word` files.

Comment: You can use python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617178/word-file-to-json-in-python

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in 2 steps:

1. Extract the data from the .docx file to `txt` or `xml`
2. Now use SSIS to import. (Azure Data Factory if you are in the cloud)

Comment: Isn't there really any ELT tool that supports Word files? Because doing everything without the help of a tool is a huge load of work. I'm focusing on `Big Data` here. So It doesn't seem practical to extract and import loads of Word files onto a database one by one. Even if I extract Word files into a `txt` file or so, it doesn't support content like images. What to do then?

Comment: Also, what about the `data transformation` part that should happen before importing data to the database? Like identifying the same kind of data and sorting them under categories and stuff... Should everything be done manually?